# "Search Online Templates" not querying properly in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

For any project type in VS2008(TS), when I select "Search Online Templates" and click OK, the VS2008 Documentation window opens as expected, but it never automatically queries anything.  The contents panel has nothing selected, and the search panel has no query and no search results.  I've tried it when set to online first or local first, it makes no difference.

Is this correctable?